# Let f be a differentiable function such that $\lim_{x\to +∞} f(x)=-∞$ and $\lim_{x\to -∞} f(x)=-∞$ , then f has a stationary point

Tags: real-analysis

My proof idea was that the function must intuitively be increasing for some $x_1<0$ and decreasing for some $x_2>0$, so this would mean that $f'(x_1)>0$ and $f'(x_2)<0$. Using the intermediate zero theorem, I can then conclude that there exists $x_3∈[x_1,x_2]$ such that $f'(x_3)=0$. The problem is I'm stuck trying to prove the fact that those two points with negative and positive derivatives exist.

Comment: Can you use the fact that a continuous function on a closed bounded interval achieves its maximum and minimum?

Comment: Intermediate value theorem + Rolle.

Comment: @JasonDeVito The point might also be on the boundary of the closed bounded interval you choose, so it might not be a stationary point

Comment: @SamueleMonitto:  I understand, but for questions like this, it's still important to know what tools you have access to and which you don't.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a way to prove the existence of your $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Because $\lim_{x\rightarrow -\infty} f(x) = -\infty$, there is an $a<0$ with the property that $f(x) < f(0)-1$ for all $x < a$.

Similarly, because $\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(x) = -\infty$, there is a $b>0$ with the property that $f(x) < f(0) - 1$ for all $x > b$.

Then $f(a) \leq f(0) - 1$.  So, by the Mean Value theorem, there is an $
x_1\in (a,0)$ with $f'(x_1) = \frac{f(0) - f(a)}{0-a}$, and $f'(x_1) > 0$ since $-a > 0$ and $f(0) -f(a)\geq 1$.

Similarly, $f(b) \leq f(0) - 1$, so by the Mean Value theorem, there is an $x_2\in(0,b)$ with $f'(x_2) = \frac{f(b) - f(0)}{b-0}$, and $f'(x_2)< 0$ since $f(b) - f(0) \leq -1$ and $b>0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I know I might have complicated the problem unnecessarily but I was invested in the proof at this point. Also why do we need the -1? Can't we simply use f(x)<f(0)?

Comment: @SamueleMonitto:  The point of the $-1$ is to establish the strict inequality $f'(x_1) > 0$ and likewise for $f'(x_2)$.  (I will edit these strict inequalities in shortly!)  Any negative number would have worked in place of $-1$.

Answer (score 2):

Your way is correct and we can refer to [Extreme value theorem (EVT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extreme_value_theorem) to conclude that $f:[x_1,x_2]\to \mathbb R$ as a maximum which is also a stationary point since the function is differentiable.

In a simpler way we can show that $\exists a,b$ such that $f(a)=f(b)$ and then refer to [Rolle's theorem][2].

---

Following your idea, we have that $\exists a_1$ such that $f(a_1)<0$ then $\exists a_2<a_1$ such that $f(a_2)<f(a_1)<0$, then we can conclude by MVT that $\exists a\in (a_2,a_1)$ such that $f'(a)\>0$.

Comment: I like the second way, thanks a lot, I think it's a bit easier than my way. However, I'm missing how I can show that the function is increasing and decreasing on x1 and x2 with the limits hypothesis. I have the intuition but I wouldn't know how to write a real proof.

Comment: @SamueleMonitto The idea is to consider $a<b$ and then let $m=min (f(a),f(b))$. Assume  wlog $f(a)=m$ then since $\lim_{x\to \infty} f(x)=-\infty$ by IVT we can find $b'>a$ such that $f(b')=m$.

Comment: I think there was a misunderstanding,I wasn't clear enough in my question. I was asking about my proof idea and how I might be able to prove that there are two points with negative and positive derivatives,

Comment: In any case, thanks for the prompt, I was able to write the proof with the other method, however at this point I am also invested in solving it the other way.

Comment: @SamueleMonitto Ah ok! That's fine. I'll take a look to that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $F: [-\pi/2, \pi/2] \to \mathbb{R}$ be the function defined by:

$$F(t) :=\begin{cases} \arctan f(\tan t) &\text{, if } - \pi/2 < t < \pi/2 \\ -\pi/2 &\text{, if } t = \pm\pi/2\end{cases}$$

then $F$ Is continuous on $[-\pi/2, \pi/2]$, differentiable on $]-\pi/2, \pi/2[$ and takes the same value at the endpoints.
By Rolle's Theorem, there exists $\tau \in ]\pi/2, \pi/2[$ s.t. $F^\prime (\tau) =0$; but:

$$F^\prime (t) = \frac{1}{1 + f^2 (\tan t)}\ f^\prime (\tan t)\ \frac{1}{\cos^2 t}$$

hence $f^\prime (\tan \tau) =0$.

Comment: Perhaps, you should have written $$F^\prime (t) = \frac{1}{1 + f^2(\tan t)}\ f^\prime(\tan t)\ \frac{1}{\cos^2 t}\;.$$

Comment: Yep, sorry for the typo.

Comment: Do not worry, you are welcome. Congratulations for your proof, you have had a good idea.